# Correct configuration of a reverse Proxy with IIS 6.0 and IIRF for Hudson

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, reverse-proxy, hudson

I have an Hudson build working on IIS 6.0 with reverse proxy (IIRF). 
In general it works but 2 errors are displayed in Hudson in the main configuration page called "Manage Hudson" (only if I connect through the reverse proxy):

1. Your container doesn't use UTF-8 to decode URLs. If you use non-ASCII characters as a job name etc, this will cause problems. See Containers and Tomcat i18n for more details.
2. It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken

This is my configuration of IIRF:

```
RewriteLog C:\logsIIRF.txt
RewriteLogLevel 2

IterationLimit 10
MaxMatchCount 10
RewriteEngine ON
StatusInquiry ON
UrlDecoding 0FF


# add a trailing slash:
RedirectRule ^/hudson$  /hudson/    [I]

# Does the reverse Proxy
ProxyPass ^/hudson/(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/hudson/$1  [I]
ProxyPassReverse  /hudson http://localhost:8080/hudson
```

Any suggestion on how to get rid of those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Enable UTF-8 on the IIS server like this:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/30e5b949-3c83-4b4a-b17e-f4f12e3b3743.mspx?mfr=true

Though the option just states that you enable UTF-8 for logging purposes, the article mentions that it might be necessary, when rewriting URL's with non-English characters